# Non uniform Riffle of two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have

```
x = {b1, b2}
```

and

```
y = {{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}, {a5, a6}}
```

I want to produce the riffle'd list

```
z = {{{b1, a1}, {b2, a2}}, {{b1, a3}, {b2, a4}}, {{b1, a5}, {b2, a6}}}
```

[image]

**Attempt**

I have produced this horible code

```
riffle[a_, b_] := Riffle[a, b, {1, -1, 2}]
tt = Reverse /@ MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {x, Transpose@y}, 1]; 
Partition[#, 2] & /@ Map[riffle @@ ## &, tt, {1}] // Transpose
```

which does the trick but...

**Question**

> I am fairly certain there should be a simpler method?

Thank you for your help in seeking elegance in mathematica!

Comment: Why isn't `Transpose[{{b1, b2}, #}] & /@ {{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}, {a5, a6}}` sufficient?

Comment: @J.M. because you are smart and I am dumb :-). Either write it as an answer or I delete my post?

Comment: I would prefer you answer your own question, if you can explain why it works. ;)

Comment: @J.M. so now I accept my own  (i.e.  your's) answer?  I feel its a bit cheeky!

Comment: It would be less cheeky if you added an explanation why it works, you know. ;) (However, I cannot give a second upvote.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
x = {b1, b2};
y = {{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}, {a5, a6}};
```

(As suggested in the comments by user1066)

```
Inner[{#2, #1}&, y, x, List]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  \{\text{b1},\text{a1}\} & \{\text{b2},\text{a2}\} \\
>  \{\text{b1},\text{a3}\} & \{\text{b2},\text{a4}\} \\
>  \{\text{b1},\text{a5}\} & \{\text{b2},\text{a6}\} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

My earlier solution:

```
Inner[Reverse@*List, y, x, List]
```

Timing comparisons:

```
i1 = First@RepeatedTiming[ai1 = Inner[{#2, #1} &, y, x, List]];
i2 = First@RepeatedTiming[ai2 = Inner[Reverse@*List, y, x, List]];
t = First@RepeatedTiming[at = Transpose[{x, #}] & /@ y];
{i2, t}/i1
```

> {1.54407, 2.7154}

It gives a 1.5x speed up, and 2.7x compared to using [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html).

```
ai1 == ai2 == at
```

> True

Comment: +1 Looks elegant. Would you kindly explain how it works?  I find it difficult to follow, even after reading about Inner.

Comment: @DavidC First evaluate `Inner[f, y, x, g]`. Then you can better see why the values of `g` and `f` are `List` and `Reverse@*List`.

Comment: Actually J. M.'s [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) solution is simpler and better than this.

Comment: @David, to put Suba's explanation in another way: think of what happens when you take the usual dot product of a matrix and a vector, and consider what happens if you replace the addition and the multiplication with something else.

Comment: @user1066 Thanks. That speeds it up a little. And it appears that the [`Inner`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html) solution is faster than that using [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html).

Answer (score 9):

as suggested by @J.M. (who gets all the credit) there is in fact a very simple solution (as I feared! :-) ):

```
  Transpose[{{b1, b2}, #}] & /@ {{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}, {a5, a6}}
```

**Why it works**

Well, it seems obvious a posteriori  ( :-) ) 
especially since JM's solution is elegant and simple.

The mapping takes in turn `{a1, a2}`, `{a3, a4}` ...
and applies `{{b1, b2}, #}&` to each list
so that we have a list of

```
 {{b1, b2},{a1, a2}},  {{b1, b2},{a3, a4}}...
```

Thanks to the `Transpose` it becomes

```
  {{b1, a1}, {b2, a2}}, {{b1, a3}, {b2, a4}}...
```

Hence the result.

**Postscript**

My own clumsy solution arose because I failed to realise that the length of `{b1,b2}` was always 2.

Comment: I use this exact same transpose method to take some list of x values and disperse it to a list of lists of different y values! Very cool.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this?

```
x = {b1, b2};
y = {{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}, {a5, a6}};
z = {{{b1, a1}, {b2, a2}}, {{b1, a3}, {b2, a4}}, {{b1, a5}, {b2,a6}}};
Partition[#, 2] & /@ Riffle @@@ Table[{x, k}, {k, y}]
%==z
```

{{{b1, a1}, {b2, a2}}, {{b1, a3}, {b2, a4}}, {{b1, a5}, {b2, a6}}}

True

---

The first step:

```
t = Table[{x, k}, {k, y}]
```

{{{b1, b2}, {a1, a2}}, {{b1, b2}, {a3, a4}}, {{b1, b2}, {a5, a6}}}

---

The second step:

```
Riffle@@@ t
```

{{b1, a1, b2, a2}, {b1, a3, b2, a4}, {b1, a5, b2, a6}}

---

Then all that's needed is to `Partition` each sublist. For example,

```
Partition[{{b1, a1, b2, a2},2]
```

{{b1,a1},{b2,a2}}

Answer (score 2):

```
x = {b1, b2};

y = {{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}, {a5, a6}};
```

Using `Threaded` (new in 13.1)

```
Map[Reverse, y + Threaded[x] /. Plus :> List, {2}]
```

returns

```
{{{b1, a1}, {b2, a2}}, 
 {{b1, a3}, {b2, a4}}, 
 {{b1, a5}, {b2, a6}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = {b1, b2};

y = {{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}, {a5, a6}};
```

---

An alternative to use `Riffle` directly is as follows:

```
Thread /@ Partition[Riffle[Array[x &, Length@y], y], 2]

(*{{{b1, a1}, {b2, a2}}, {{b1, a3}, {b2, a4}}, {{b1, a5}, {b2, a6}}}*)
```

Or using `Table` and `Thread`:

```
Thread /@ Table[{x, k}, {k, y}]

(*{{{b1, a1}, {b2, a2}}, {{b1, a3}, {b2, a4}}, {{b1, a5}, {b2, a6}}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = {b1, b2};
y = {{a1, a2}, {a3, a4}, {a5, a6}};
```

---

**Using `Thread`:**

```
res = Thread[{x, #}] & /@ y

MatrixForm /@ {x, y, res}
```

---

**Using `Riffle`:**

```
Riffle[x, #] & /@ y // Map[Partition[#, 2] &]
```

---

*Result:*

[image]